# How to edit / update values in CRUD application in ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs, state, crud

Trying to add the ability for, when a user adds an item to the table, to edit the values once they hit the edit button.

Code under Edit Project below in my code isn't working. I've tried to research a bunch of different ways on how to do this, but I keep coming up short.

Any idea on how I can do this easily?

Link to [codesandbox](https://codesandbox.io/s/nifty-solomon-2ffvw?fontsize=14&hidenavigation=1&theme=dark).

MainCrud.js

```
import React, { useState } from "react";

import CrudIntro from "../crud/crudIntro/crudIntro";
import CrudAdd from "../crud/crudAdd/crudAdd";
import CrudTable from "../crud/crudTable/crudTable";

const MainCrud = props => {
  // Initiazle project data
  const projectData = [];

  // Initial state for edit button's hidden state to be false
  const [editBtn, setEditBtn] = useState(false);

  // Initialize state of the project data above to 'projects'
  const [projects, setProject] = useState(projectData);

  // Add Project
  const addProject = project => {
    // Create new item with a unique ID
    project.id = projects.length + 1;
    // Take the current list, and add onto it via the spread operator
    setProject([...projects, project]);
  };

  // Delete Project
  const deleteProject = id => {
    setProject(projects.filter(project => project.id !== id));
  };

  // Edit Project
  const editProject = e => {
    setEditBtn(true);
    this.setState({
      ...this.state.name,
      ...this.state.description,
      ...this.state.date,
      [e.target.name]: e.target.value
    });
  };

  return (
    <div>
      <section id="add">
        <CrudIntro title={props.title} subTitle={props.subTitle} />
        <CrudAdd addProject={addProject} />
      </section>
      <section id="main">
        <CrudTable
          projectData={projects}
          editProject={editProject}
          deleteProject={deleteProject}
        />
      </section>
    </div>
  );
};

export default MainCrud;
```

Answer (score 0):

I see you are trying to do `this.setState` in a functional component, which you can't do. `this` will point to `undefined` in this case